# Progress Dialog: android.view.WindowLeaked: has leaked window DecorView@6995336[] that was originally added here

Tags: java, android

I tried to change the orientation of my device on recycler view but it always crashes when progress dialog shows up.

How to solve this?

Here is my code:

private class LoadOrdersListAgent extends AsyncTask {

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(OrdersActivity.this);
        ordersList = new ArrayList<>();
        rvor = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_orders_agent);
        emptytv = findViewById(R.id.empty_view_orders_agent);
        emptytv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        rvor.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rvor.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(OrdersActivity.this));
        rvor.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        dialog.setMessage("Loading....");
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        final OrdersAdapter adapter = new OrdersAdapter(getApplicationContext(), ordersList);
        rvor.setAdapter(adapter);
        rvor.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(OrdersActivity.this));
        srl.setRefreshing(false);

        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

        if (ordersList.isEmpty()) {
            Log.d("TESTING.....", "LIST OF ORDERS ----->" + ordersList);
            rvor.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            srl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            emptytv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            rvor.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            srl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            emptytv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        ordersList = OrdersApi.getOrders(url, key);
        return null;
    }
}

private void swipeOrderLayout() {
    srl = findViewById(R.id.swipe);

    srl.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            if (new CheckNetworkUtil(OrdersActivity.this).isNetworkAvailable()) {
                new LoadOrdersListAgent().execute();
```

//                    new LoadOrdersListAdmin().execute();
                } else
                    Toast.makeText(OrdersActivity.this, "No Internet Connection!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                srl.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });
    }

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when i was Finishing/Destroying the activity without Dismissing  progress Dialogue.

Solution use `dialog.dismiss();` to dismiss the progress dialogue before destroying or pausing the activity

in your case remove the if condition and just call `dialog.dismiss();` in postExecute method

Comment: crashing is still exists.

Comment: can you post the full activity code from where this asynctask is begin executed

Comment: Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        checkInternetConnection();

}

private void checkInternetConnection() {
        if (new CheckNetworkUtil(OrdersActivity.this).isNetworkAvailable()) {
            new LoadOrdersListAgent().execute();
//            new LoadOrdersListAdmin().execute();
        } else
            Toast.makeText(OrdersActivity.this, "No Internet Connection!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

Comment: super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_orders_agent);

Answer (score 0):

Declare your ProgressDialog in Global using :

Add this code above onCreate() :

```
private ProgressDialog dialog;
```

Add this code within a onCreate():

```
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(OrdersActivity.this);
    dialog.setMessage("Loading....");
    dialog.show();
```

Add this code within as onPreExecute method ,

```
 if (!dialog.isShowing()) {
        dialog.show();
    }
```